# Spring security ошибка при авторизации (403)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Пробую сделать произвольный AuthenticationProvider. Пока просто поставил *println*, чтобы он высвечивал данные о пользователе, если в него система обратится.
И вот тут начинается странное:

Берем конфигурацию из офф. документации:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated() 
        .and()
    .formLogin()                      
        .and()
    .httpBasic();
```

В терминале логин\пароль высвечивается.
Берем следующий конфиг:

```
http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login");
```

Создаем запрос:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/in", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(){
    return "login";
}
```

И вьюшку:

```
form.ui.form(action="/login", method="post")
                h4.ui.dividing.header Авторизация
                .field
                    label Логин
                    input(name="username" placeholder="Логин" type="text")
                .field
                    label Пароль
                    input(name="password" placeholder="Пароль" type="password")
                button.ui.button(type="submit") Submit
```

Страница открывается, но при нажатии submit выскакивает ошибка 403. К AuthenticationProvider обращений не было.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел вчера ответ, да и сегодня на английском so ответили:

Если посмотреть на примеры, там можно увидеть 3е поле ввода

```
<input type="hidden"                        
    name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
    value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

А во вьюшке, что я написал в вопросе ее нет. Это защита csrf, которая включена по умолчанию. Чтобы все заработало, нужно добавить такое поле или отключить этот функционал.

```
http.csrf().disabled();
```